# Exception: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app by flutter with firebase phone number authentication, when I input the phone number and automatically go to internet browser to do the  Play Integrity checks to make sure that is not robot, but when is finished the app is stopped and this message appear (Exception: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful).

[The Exception Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT5pH.png)

This the error patch code

```
part of "core_patch.dart";

@patch
class Error {
  @patch
  static String _objectToString(Object object) {
    return Object._toString(object);
  }

  @patch
  static String _stringToSafeString(String string) {
    return json.encode(string);
  }

  @patch
  StackTrace? get stackTrace => _stackTrace;

  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  StackTrace? _stackTrace;

  @patch
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "Error_throwWithStackTrace")
  external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
}

class _AssertionError extends Error implements AssertionError {
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  _AssertionError._create(
      this._failedAssertion, this._url, this._line, this._column, this.message);

  // AssertionError_throwNew in errors.cc fishes the assertion source code
  // out of the script. It expects a Dart stack frame from class
  // _AssertionError. Thus we need a Dart stub that calls the native code.
  @pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
  static _throwNew(int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message) {
    _doThrowNew(assertionStart, assertionEnd, message);
  }

  @pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
  @pragma('vm:never-inline')
  static _throwNewNullAssertion(String name, int line, int column) {
    _doThrowNewSource('$name != null', line, column, null);
  }

  @pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNew")
  external static _doThrowNew(
      int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message);
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "AssertionError_throwNewSource")
  external static _doThrowNewSource(
      String failedAssertion, int line, int column, Object? message);

  @pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
  static _evaluateAssertion(condition) {
    if (identical(condition, true) || identical(condition, false)) {
      return condition;
    }
    if (condition is _Closure) {
      return (condition as dynamic Function())();
    }
    if (condition is Function) {
      condition = (condition as dynamic Function())();
    }
    return condition;
  }

  String get _messageString {
    final msg = message;
    if (msg == null) return "is not true.";
    if (msg is String) return msg;
    return Error.safeToString(msg);
  }

  String toString() {
    if (_url == null) {
      if (message == null) return _failedAssertion.trim();
      return "'${_failedAssertion.trim()}': $_messageString";
    }
    var columnInfo = "";
    if (_column > 0) {
      // Only add column information if it is valid.
      columnInfo = " pos $_column";
    }
    return "'$_url': Failed assertion: line $_line$columnInfo: "
        "'$_failedAssertion': $_messageString";
  }

  final String _failedAssertion;
  final String? _url;
  final int _line;
  final int _column;
  final Object? message;
}

class _TypeError extends Error implements TypeError {
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  _TypeError._create(this._url, this._line, this._column, this._message);

  @pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "TypeError_throwNew")
  external static _throwNew(
      int location, Object srcValue, _Type dstType, String dstName);

  String toString() => _message;

  final String? _url;
  final int? _line;
  final int? _column;
  final String _message;
}

class _InternalError {
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  const _InternalError(this._msg);
  String toString() => "InternalError: '${_msg}'";
  final String _msg;
}

@patch
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
class UnsupportedError {
  static _throwNew(String msg) {
    throw new UnsupportedError(msg);
  }
}

@patch
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
class StateError {
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static _throwNew(String msg) {
    throw new StateError(msg);
  }
}

/// Error thrown when a lazily initialized variable cannot be initialized.
///
/// Cyclic dependencies are no longer detected at runtime in null safe code.
/// Such code will fail in other ways instead,
/// possibly with a [StackOverflowError].
///
/// Will be removed when support for non-null-safe code is discontinued.
@Deprecated("Remove when no longer supporting non-null-safe code.")
class _CyclicInitializationError extends Error {
  final String? variableName;
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  _CyclicInitializationError([this.variableName]);
  String toString() {
    var variableName = this.variableName;
    return variableName == null
        ? "Reading static variable during its initialization"
        : "Reading static variable '$variableName' during its initialization";
  }

  static _throwNew(String variableName) {
    throw new _CyclicInitializationError(variableName);
  }
}

@patch
class NoSuchMethodError {
  final Object? _receiver;
  final Invocation _invocation;

  @patch
  factory NoSuchMethodError.withInvocation(
          Object? receiver, Invocation invocation) =
      NoSuchMethodError._withInvocation;

  NoSuchMethodError._withInvocation(this._receiver, this._invocation);

  static void _throwNewInvocation(Object? receiver, Invocation invocation) {
    throw new NoSuchMethodError.withInvocation(receiver, invocation);
  }

  // The compiler emits a call to _throwNew when it cannot resolve a static
  // method at compile time. The receiver is actually the literal class of the
  // unresolved method.
  @pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
  static void _throwNew(
      Object receiver,
      String memberName,
      int invocationType,
      int typeArgumentsLength,
      Object? typeArguments,
      List? arguments,
      List? argumentNames) {
    throw new NoSuchMethodError._withType(receiver, memberName, invocationType,
        typeArgumentsLength, typeArguments, arguments, argumentNames);
  }

  // Helper to build a map of named arguments.
  static Map<Symbol, dynamic> _NamedArgumentsMap(
      List arguments, List argumentNames) {
    Map<Symbol, dynamic> namedArguments = new Map<Symbol, dynamic>();
    int numPositionalArguments = arguments.length - argumentNames.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < argumentNames.length; i++) {
      final argValue = arguments[numPositionalArguments + i];
      namedArguments[new Symbol(argumentNames[i])] = argValue;
    }
    return namedArguments;
  }

  // Constructor called from Exceptions::ThrowByType(kNoSuchMethod) and from
  // _throwNew above, taking a TypeArguments object rather than an unpacked list
  // of types, as well as a list of all arguments and a list of names, rather
  // than a separate list of positional arguments and a map of named arguments.
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  NoSuchMethodError._withType(
      this._receiver,
      String memberName,
      int invocationType,
      int typeArgumentsLength, // Needed with all-dynamic (null) typeArguments.
      Object? typeArguments,
      List? arguments,
      List? argumentNames)
      : this._invocation = new _InvocationMirror._withType(
            new Symbol(memberName),
            invocationType,
            _InvocationMirror._unpackTypeArguments(
                typeArguments, typeArgumentsLength),
            argumentNames != null
                ? arguments!.sublist(0, arguments.length - argumentNames.length)
                : arguments,
            argumentNames != null
                ? _NamedArgumentsMap(arguments!, argumentNames)
                : null);

  @pragma("vm:external-name", "NoSuchMethodError_existingMethodSignature")
  external static String? _existingMethodSignature(
      Object? receiver, String methodName, int invocationType);

  @patch
  String toString() {
    final localInvocation = _invocation;
    if (localInvocation is _InvocationMirror) {
      var internalName = localInvocation.memberName as internal.Symbol;
      String memberName = internal.Symbol.computeUnmangledName(internalName);

      var level = (localInvocation._type >> _InvocationMirror._LEVEL_SHIFT) &
          _InvocationMirror._LEVEL_MASK;
      var kind = localInvocation._type & _InvocationMirror._KIND_MASK;
      if (kind == _InvocationMirror._LOCAL_VAR) {
        return "NoSuchMethodError: Cannot assign to final variable '$memberName'";
      }

      StringBuffer? typeArgumentsBuf = null;
      final typeArguments = localInvocation.typeArguments;
      if ((typeArguments != null) && (typeArguments.length > 0)) {
        final argsBuf = new StringBuffer();
        argsBuf.write("<");
        for (int i = 0; i < typeArguments.length; i++) {
          if (i > 0) {
            argsBuf.write(", ");
          }
          argsBuf.write(Error.safeToString(typeArguments[i]));
        }
        argsBuf.write(">");
        typeArgumentsBuf = argsBuf;
      }
      StringBuffer argumentsBuf = new StringBuffer();
      var positionalArguments = localInvocation.positionalArguments;
      int argumentCount = 0;
      if (positionalArguments != null) {
        for (; argumentCount < positionalArguments.length; argumentCount++) {
          if (argumentCount > 0) {
            argumentsBuf.write(", ");
          }
          argumentsBuf
              .write(Error.safeToString(positionalArguments[argumentCount]));
        }
      }
      var namedArguments = localInvocation.namedArguments;
      if (namedArguments != null) {
        namedArguments.forEach((Symbol key, var value) {
          if (argumentCount > 0) {
            argumentsBuf.write(", ");
          }
          var internalName = key as internal.Symbol;
          argumentsBuf
              .write(internal.Symbol.computeUnmangledName(internalName));
          argumentsBuf.write(": ");
          argumentsBuf.write(Error.safeToString(value));
          argumentCount++;
        });
      }
      String? existingSig = _existingMethodSignature(
          _receiver, memberName, localInvocation._type);
      String argsMsg = existingSig != null ? " with matching arguments" : "";

      String kindBuf = "function";
      if (kind >= 0 && kind < 5) {
        kindBuf = (const [
          "method",
          "getter",
          "setter",
          "getter or setter",
          "variable"
        ])[kind];
      }

      StringBuffer msgBuf = new StringBuffer("NoSuchMethodError: ");
      bool isTypeCall = false;
      switch (level) {
        case _InvocationMirror._DYNAMIC:
          {
            if (_receiver == null) {
              if (existingSig != null) {
                msgBuf.writeln("The null object does not have a $kindBuf "
                    "'$memberName'$argsMsg.");
              } else {
                msgBuf
                    .writeln("The $kindBuf '$memberName' was called on null.");
              }
            } else {
              if (_receiver is _Closure) {
                msgBuf.writeln("Closure call with mismatched arguments: "
                    "function '$memberName'");
              } else if (_receiver is _Type && memberName == "call") {
                isTypeCall = true;
                String name = _receiver.toString();
                msgBuf.writeln("Attempted to use type '$name' as a function. "
                    "Since types do not define a method 'call', this is not "
                    "possible. Did you intend to call the $name constructor and "
                    "forget the 'new' operator?");
              } else {
                msgBuf
                    .writeln("Class '${_receiver.runtimeType}' has no instance "
                        "$kindBuf '$memberName'$argsMsg.");
              }
            }
            break;
          }
        case _InvocationMirror._SUPER:
          {
            msgBuf
                .writeln("Super class of class '${_receiver.runtimeType}' has "
                    "no instance $kindBuf '$memberName'$argsMsg.");
            memberName = "super.$memberName";
            break;
          }
        case _InvocationMirror._STATIC:
          {
            msgBuf.writeln("No static $kindBuf '$memberName'$argsMsg "
                "declared in class '$_receiver'.");
            break;
          }
        case _InvocationMirror._CONSTRUCTOR:
          {
            msgBuf.writeln("No constructor '$memberName'$argsMsg declared "
                "in class '$_receiver'.");
            memberName = "new $memberName";
            break;
          }
        case _InvocationMirror._TOP_LEVEL:
          {
            msgBuf.writeln("No top-level $kindBuf '$memberName'$argsMsg "
                "declared.");
            break;
          }
      }

      if (level == _InvocationMirror._TOP_LEVEL) {
        msgBuf.writeln("Receiver: top-level");
      } else {
        msgBuf.writeln("Receiver: ${Error.safeToString(_receiver)}");
      }

      if (kind == _InvocationMirror._METHOD) {
        String m = isTypeCall ? "$_receiver" : "$memberName";
        msgBuf.write("Tried calling: $m");
        if (typeArgumentsBuf != null) {
          msgBuf.write(typeArgumentsBuf);
        }
        msgBuf.write("($argumentsBuf)");
      } else if (argumentCount == 0) {
        msgBuf.write("Tried calling: $memberName");
      } else if (kind == _InvocationMirror._SETTER) {
        msgBuf.write("Tried calling: $memberName$argumentsBuf");
      } else {
        msgBuf.write("Tried calling: $memberName = $argumentsBuf");
      }

      if (existingSig != null) {
        msgBuf.write("\nFound: $memberName$existingSig");
      }

      return msgBuf.toString();
    }
    return _toStringPlain(_receiver, localInvocation);
  }

  /// Creates a string representation of an invocation.
  ///
  /// Used for situations where there is no extra information available
  /// about the failed invocation than the [Invocation] object and receiver,
  /// which includes errors created using [NoSuchMethodError.withInvocation].
  static String _toStringPlain(Object? receiver, Invocation invocation) {
    var name = _symbolToString(invocation.memberName);
    var receiverType = "${receiver.runtimeType}";
    if (invocation.isAccessor) {
      return "NoSuchMethodError: $receiverType has no $name "
          "${invocation.isGetter ? "getter" : "setter"}";
    }
    var buffer = StringBuffer("NoSuchMethodError")..write(": ");
    buffer.write("$receiverType has no $name method accepting arguments ");
    var separator = "";
    if (invocation.typeArguments.isNotEmpty) {
      buffer.write("<");
      for (var type in invocation.typeArguments) {
        buffer
          ..write(separator)
          ..write("_");
        separator = ", ";
      }
      buffer.write(">");
      separator = "";
    }
    buffer.write("(");
    for (var argument in invocation.positionalArguments) {
      buffer
        ..write(separator)
        ..write("_");
      separator = ", ";
    }
    if (invocation.namedArguments.isNotEmpty) {
      buffer
        ..write(separator)
        ..write("{");
      separator = "";
      for (var name in invocation.namedArguments.keys) {
        buffer
          ..write(separator)
          ..write(_symbolToString(name))
          ..write(": _");
        separator = ",";
      }
      buffer.write("}");
    }
    buffer.write(")");
    return buffer.toString();
  }

  static String _symbolToString(Symbol symbol) {
    if (symbol is internal.Symbol) {
      return internal.Symbol.computeUnmangledName(symbol);
    }
    return "$symbol";
  }
}

@pragma("vm:entry-point")
class _CompileTimeError extends Error {
  final String _errorMsg;
  _CompileTimeError(this._errorMsg);
  String toString() => _errorMsg;
}

/// Used by Fasta to report a runtime error when a final field with an
/// initializer is also initialized in a generative constructor.
///
/// Note: in strong mode, this is a compile-time error and this class becomes
/// obsolete.
class _DuplicatedFieldInitializerError extends Error {
  final String _name;

  _DuplicatedFieldInitializerError(this._name);

  toString() => "Error: field '$_name' is already initialized.";
}

// Implementations needed to implement the `_stackTrace` member added
// in the @patch class of [Error].

@patch
class OutOfMemoryError {
  StackTrace? get _stackTrace =>
      throw UnsupportedError('OutOfMemoryError._stackTrace');
  void set _stackTrace(StackTrace? _) {
    throw UnsupportedError('OutOfMemoryError._stackTrace');
  }
}

@patch
class StackOverflowError {
  StackTrace? get _stackTrace =>
      throw UnsupportedError('StackOverflowError._stackTrace');
  void set _stackTrace(StackTrace? _) {
    throw UnsupportedError('StackOverflowError._stackTrace');
  }
}

@patch
class IntegerDivisionByZeroException {
  StackTrace? get _stackTrace =>
      throw UnsupportedError('IntegerDivisionByZeroException._stackTrace');
  void set _stackTrace(StackTrace? _) {
    throw UnsupportedError('IntegerDivisionByZeroException._stackTrace');
  }
}
```

This class of AuthProvider

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  bool _isSignedIn = false;
  bool get isSignedIn => _isSignedIn;

  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  String? _uid;
  String get uid => _uid!;

  UserModel? _userModel;
  UserModel get userModel => _userModel!;

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  AuthProvider(){
    checkSign();
  }

  void checkSign() async{
   final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _isSignedIn = sharedPreferences.getBool('is_signedin') ?? false ;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future setSignIn()async{
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setBool('is_signedin', true);
    _isSignedIn=true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // sign in
  void signInWithPhone (BuildContext context, String phoneNumber, String pharmacyName,String password) async{
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    try {
      
      await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential  phoneAuthCredential) async{
          await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        },
        verificationFailed: (error){
          _isLoading = false;
          notifyListeners();
          showSnackBar(context, 'faild verification');
          throw Exception(error.message);
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => OtpScreen(
                verificationId: verificationId,
                pharmacyName: pharmacyName,
                phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                password: password,
              ),
            ),
          );
           _isLoading = false;
           notifyListeners();
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
      );

     
      
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (!context.mounted) return;
      showSnackBar(context, e.toString());
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  // verify otp
  void verifyOtp({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String verificationId,
    required String userOtp,
    required Function onSuccess,
  }) async{
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential creds = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: userOtp,
      );

      User user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(creds)).user!;

      // carry our logic
      _uid = user.uid;
      onSuccess();
          
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (!context.mounted) return;
      showSnackBar(context, e.message.toString());
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  //Database operation
  Future<bool> checkExistingUser() async{
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _firebaseFirestore.collection('users').doc(_uid).get();
    if(snapshot.exists){
      print('User Exist');
      return true;
    }
    else {
      print('New User');
      return false;
    }
  }

  void saveUserDataToFirebase({
    required BuildContext context,
    required UserModel userModel,
    required Function onSuccess,
  })async{
    _isLoading =true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {

      userModel.uid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;
      _userModel= userModel;     

      // uploading to database
      await _firebaseFirestore.collection('users').doc(_uid).set(userModel.toMap()).then((value) {
        onSuccess();
        _isLoading= false;
        notifyListeners();
      });
      
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (!context.mounted) return;
      showSnackBar(context, e.message.toString());

      _isLoading=false;
      notifyListeners();
    }

  }

  // store data locally
  Future saveUserDataToSP()async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await sharedPreferences.setString('user_model', jsonEncode(userModel.toMap()));
  }
}
```

I tried all this:

1. I added the  SHA1 and SHA-256 in my firebase account.
2. I added dependency in build.gradle(:app) implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'.
3. I enabled api and services "Google Play Integrity API" on google cloud console.
4. I downloaded and replaced the latest google-services.json file in my project.
5. I cleaned and rebuilt project.

But the problem is still not soloved

Comment: In what device are you testing? this feature cannot be tested in a emulator